# Bridge table primary as foreign key in another table (JPA)

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, database-design, nhibernate-mapping

I'm designing a student enrollment database

`Student-Table
  student_id (pk) 
  //other attributes`

`Course-Table
  course_id (pk)
  //other attributes`

`Student_course-Table
  student_course_id(pk)
  course_id (fk)
  student_id (fk)`

`Lectrue-Table
  lecture_id(pk)
  student_course_id(fk - > student_course table)
  // other attributes`

Basically I want to store which student is enrolled to which course and has attend how many lectures for that particular course.

Q1 ) Is this design correct? Should I use primary key of Bridge table  as foreign key in another table.
Q2 ) I did  manyToMany mapping between student <-> course and oneToMany between student_course <-> lecture and got the following error :

org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Any idea how to proceed?

//UPDATE Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "courseName")
    private Map<String, Course> courses;


}

@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"COURSE_NAME"}))
public class Course implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COURSE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_COURSE", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") })
    private Set<Student> students;

    @Column(name = "COURSE_NAME")
    private String courseName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "LECTURE")
public class Lecture {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LECTURE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;



    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_COURSE_ID")
    private StudentCourse studentCourse;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_COURSE")

public class StudentCourse {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_COURSE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(name = "COURSE_ID")
    private Long courseId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentCourse")
    private Set<Lecture> lectures = new HashSet<Lecture>();
    }
```

Comment: show us the entity classes

Comment: @MaciejKowalski : entity classes added